# Stop Restkit from mapping all results

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have a project where I am setting up all responseDescriptors (8 of them) and mappings (8 of them) when my RestEngine class is established... I set them up ahead of time rather during each call. *I am not sure if this good practice or not.*

The issue is that one of my descriptors seems to be mapping all results when it shouldn't.

**I think the issue lies in my thingDescriptor or it could be the following route (v1/things/:thingID\.json), but this route is a GET so I wouldn't think my POST request would go through this route?**

Here is the POST request I am making that is getting a result mapped to a specific CLASS which it shouldn't be or rather I don't want it to be mapped to a specific class.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil
                                           path:@"v1/things/request.json"
                                     parameters:@{
                                                     @"auth_token" : self.accessToken,
                                                     @"api_key" : self.api_key,
                                                     @"lat" : lat,
                                                     @"lng" : lng
                                                 }
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                            RKLogInfo(@"Post request of an Thing Request start tracking request update...");

<-- the mappingResult shows its mapped to a Thing class but I want server response to mapped to an NSDictionary instead? 

                                        }
                                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            RKLogError(@"Post request of an Thing Request failed with error: %@", error);
                                        }];
```

Here are my mappings that are setup:

```
// Routes for Things
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Thing class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/things/:thingID\\.json"
                                                         method:RKRequestMethodGET]];


[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:kRouteUpdateThingLoc
                                                   pathPattern:@"v1/things/update_location.json"
                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];

 [objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Thing class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/things.json"
                                                         method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];

// Register our mappings with the provider
RKResponseDescriptor *thingResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:thingMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"v1/things.json"
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKResponseDescriptor *thingDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:thingMapping
                                                                               pathPattern:@"v1/things/:thingID.json"
                                                                                   keyPath:nil
                                                                               statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. You want to make a POST request without mapping to an object? Don't use RestKit, rest kit will try to map the data to the object. Instead use AFNetworking if you're simply looking for a json to nsdictionary response. It's what RestKit is using below the Object Mapping of RestKit.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I didn't know if Restkit allowed you to just make a call without mapping.

Comment: It might, but it's not really it's intended purpose. You should already have AFNetworking in your project though right? I can give you a quick sample if you aren't familiar with using it.

Comment: Please give an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some typos above:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://my.herokuapp.com/"]];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"api_key" : self.api_key,
                             @"acode" : code
                             };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"v1/users/approve_by_code.json" parameters:parameters];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"THIS IS A DICTIONARY (or array): %@", JSON);
    object:nil];
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"if requestFailed");
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AFNetworking Like So:

```
    AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:@"v1/"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                @"auth_token" : self.accessToken,
                                @"api_key" : self.api_key,
                                @"lat" : lat,
                                @"lng" : lng
                                };

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"things/request.json" parameters:parameters];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *opertaion = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:responseObject success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"THIS IS A DICTIONARY (or array): %@", JSON);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"if requestFailed");
    }];
```